# Python: access multiple elements in list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
my_list = ["shanya", 1.2, 1, False, "test", 2, 3.3, True, "3", "4.0"]
```

But how do I access multiple elements in this list?

I know how to access one specific element (e.g., `my_list[1]` gives me `[1.2]`) and a range (e.g., `my_list[1:3]` gives me `[1.2, 1]`) but how do I get the first and third to last element?

```
["shanya", 1, False, "test", 2, 3.3, True, "3", "4.0"]
```

Comment: Index `1` will give you the second item. If you want the first item you need to use `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply contact the sub-lists, like:

```
result = l[:1] + l[2:]
```

output:

```
['shanya', 1, False, 'test', 2, 3.3, True, '3', '4.0']
```

Comment: ok I have to use the "range" (a to b) instead of specifying one element [a]. Otherwise I get an error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list`

Comment: @rororo sounds like your "float" is not in a list

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> values = ["shanya", 1.2, 1, False, "test", 2, 3.3, True, "3", "4.0"]

>>> itemgetter(0, -3)(values)
('shanya', True)
```